# Setup and Deployment of web application

Tags: web-applications, wix, inno-setup, setup-deployment

I have an a web application I like to distribute and install, with Apache web server (xampp), SQL Server Express.

I am really new in setup and deployment of application. And I just begin reading on windows installer, wix, innosetup which requires steep learning curve. Before diving further, I'm not sure if it can achieve what I need, hence my questions.

Is it possible and what is easiest tool to create a setup file that install in chain of xampp, sql server plus some configuration of apache host, php extension? All packed in one setup package.

Answer (score 2):

I've built installer with inno, Wix and Burn. So I'll give you a quick comparison of then.

Wix : Very steep learning curve. Difficult if you need anything other than a file copy install. You'll also need to learn how to use Heat.exe to generate some of your install from folders. If you must have msi installers, it's the way to go but difficult.

Burn : Much easier than Wix, but is really a way to wrap msi installers together.

Inno : Much easier to work with. Free tooling and wizards make it simple to get going. Install logic can be coded in pascal, rather than the convoluted custom actions in Wix. Highly recommended. Only down side is it produces an exe and not an msi.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of windows installer.

Firstly, you can spend  your time on Wix and windows installer. Windows installer is like a framework which provides all the infrastructure to allow developers to install their applications by making use of  .msi packages on the windows platform.

Wix is kind of an editor which can be used to build .msi packages which leverage the windows installer service to install applications. There are a lot of install editors available in the market today. Examples are installshield, installanywhere, advanced installer etc. InnoSetup is also one of such a kind.
I can assure you that Wix is the industry standard and offers a lot more functionality and flexibility than anything else out there.
However, to make use of wix effectively, you will need a good  understanding of windows installer.

So Windows installer and Wix is all you need to help with your requirements.

Yes, very much. Wix is sophisticated enough to handle all your requirements.
Wix has a bootstrapper called Burn which can help you achieve what you want to.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned Advanced Installer, here is how you can [install a PHP website](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-deploy-php-website-iis.html) or [install SQL Express](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/howto-install-sql-server-express.html).

As Kiran mentioned, this is much easy to use than Wix, but it still gives you a lot of power to configure your installer. However, you need to purchase license after the trial expires (*and you are satisfied with the results*).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible and what is easiest tool to create a setup file that install in chain of xampp, sql server plus some configuration of apache host, php extension? All packed in one setup package.

Yes, that's possible.

I'm using InnoSetup for nearly the same use-case you described in your question:

the packaging of a server stack with Nginx, PHP, additional PHP extensions, configuration and additional components. As you can see, only the components differ.

If you need inspiration, on how to realize such a InnoSetup script, 
feel free to take a look at the InnoSetup script files for the installers of the WPN-XM Server Stack over at Github:

https://github.com/WPN-XM/WPN-XM/tree/master/installers